# What is a "host only" cookie?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, jsessionid

While retrieving a form auth, the browser gets a *JSESSIONID* cookie shown as *host only*.

What is a *host only* cookie?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Host Only cookie means that the cookie should be handled by the browser to the server **only** to the same host/server that firstly sent it to the browser.

You don't want to send this host only cookie for ad campaigns, as it might contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 100):

First of all, it is not possible for `foo.com` to set a cookie that can be read by `bar.com`. `Host-only` only protects `example.com` cookies from being read by `bar.example.com`.

From [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3) regarding setting a cookie and its `Domain` attribute:

> ```
> If the domain-attribute is non-empty:
>
>   If the canonicalized request-host does not domain-match the domain-attribute:
>
>     Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.
>
>   Otherwise:
>
>     Set the cookie's host-only-flag to false.
>
>     Set the cookie's domain to the domain-attribute.
>
> Otherwise:
>
>   Set the cookie's host-only-flag to true.
>
>   Set the cookie's domain to the canonicalized request-host.
> ```

### What this means

The above can be summed up by "Host-only is the default". That is, if `Domain` is not specified, the cookie can only be read by the exact domain that has set the cookie. This can be loosened by setting the `Domain` attribute when setting a cookie.

For example, if the cookie is set by `www.example.com` and the `Domain` attribute is not specified, the cookie will be set with domain `www.example.com` and the cookie will be a host only cookie.

Another example: If the cookie is set by `www.example.com` and the `Domain` attribute is specified as `example.com` (so the cookie will be sent to `foo.example.com` too), the cookie will be set with domain `example.com` (or possibly `.example.com` by some browsers that use the dot from the previous [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) to denote *not host-only*) and the cookie will **not** be a host only cookie.

Sending of cookies is covered in section 5.4 regarding the when the cookie header is sent by the browser:

> 

```
         The cookie's host-only-flag is true and the canonicalized
         request-host is identical to the cookie's domain.
      Or:
         The cookie's host-only-flag is false and the canonicalized
         request-host domain-matches the cookie's domain.
```

So a cookie with domain `example.com` and `host-only` as false is sent to `foo.example.com` . If host-only is true, the `example.com` cookie is sent to `example.com` only.

Comment: Just ran into this on a client's website and went to look it up.  Your comment is clear and understandable.  Props for it.

Comment: Excellent description, thank you. It's worth noting that IE deliberately does not support this (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/20/internet-explorer-cookie-internals-faq/) and even latest IE 11 still sends cookies to subdomains even if the domain attribute was set.

Comment: The last sentence is wrong. It should be: "So a cookie with domain `example.com` and `host-only` as `false` is sent to `foo.example.com` . If `host-only` is `true`, the `example.com` is sent to `example.com` only."

Comment: @SkrewEverything Well spotted. The first one to spot my *_deliberate_ mistake in five years! *cough

Comment: @sparrowrt this did eventually (after your comment) get fixed in IE and Edge: “By Windows 10 RS4 (April 2018), both Edge and Internet Explorer match other browsers.” (from the FAQ you linked to)

Comment: So if I send a request to `bar.example.com` and set a cookie with domain `example.com` in the response and redirect it to `foo.example.com`, will the cookies be transferred?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie's host-only-flag is true and the canonicalized request-host is identical to the cookie's domain.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4