# Cannot delete some cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm deleting cookies with javascript  with this code

```
var arrCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < arrCookies.length; i++){

                var key = arrCookies[i].split("=");
                //var new_value = key[0].trim()+"=; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/; domain=mydomain.com";
                //document.cookie = new_value;
                var new_value = key[0].trim()+"=; max-age=0; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com"; 
                document.cookie = new_value;
                new_value = key[0].trim()+"=; max-age=0;path=/; domain=.dev.mydomain.com";  
                document.cookie = new_value;
                new_value = key[0].trim()+"=; max-age=0;path=/; domain=dev.mydomain.com";
                document.cookie = new_value;
        }
```

But there are some cookies that are note deleted its cookies are `HostOnly` ,I don't know if it's a coincidence, its possible to delete `hostonly` cookies?How?

Answer (score 0):

`HostOnly` cookies are accessible only from the same domain and subdomain (so HostOnly cookie from `foo.example.com` cannot be read and written to by `example.com`).

More on the HostOnly parameter here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28320172/3303059

Make sure the cookies you are trying to modify aren't **`HttpOnly`**. Such cookies are sent in the HTTP headers only and aren't accessible directly by JavaScript. These are usually session login tokens and this flag protects them from XSS vulnerabilities (since any injected external JS cannot read them anyway).